# What was president Ayub Khan's plan on the eastern front during the Indo-Pakistan war of 1965?

Tags: india, pakistan, bangladesh

Surprisingly, the Indo-Pakistan war of 1965 was concentrated on the western front only. That is because the war lasted only 17 days and ended up in a ceasefire.

After the 1965 war, one of the accusations floated by Sheik Mujibur Rahman and the Awami League against West Pakistan was that they didn't have any plan for the protection of East Pakistan against a possible Indian attack during the war of 1965.

It is hard to imagine that Ayub Khan kept himself focused on the western front only and kept the eastern front unsupervised.

What was president Ayub Khan's plan on the eastern front during the war of 1965 against a possible Indian attack?

**N.B.** This is one of the unanswered mysteries of the pre-1971 history of undivided Pakistan. No books I have read so far answer this question, not even Ayub Khan's own autobiography.

Comment: It is not clear that Ayub Khan had any plans outside Kashmir and Jammu and had not considered the risk of a second front.  Even an Indian advance towards Lahore in northern Punjab was poorly defended, and that is not too far away from Kashmir.  The border further south, let alone half a continent away in Bengal, seems not to have entered into his thoughts at all.

Comment: The only possible plan would be to have troops pre-stationed in East Pakistan. There'd be no feasible way to move them there in a timely manner after the start of hostilities. If that wasn't being done, then the league was right that there was no plan (which explains why you can't find one).